# PhoneGap: use PHP to create the HTML?

Tags: php, cordova

I want to make apps for iPhone and Android, but as an enthusiastic PHP-programmer, I'm not really willing to learn Java or C++.  So I ran into PhoneGap.

BUT... I don't really like programming in pure HTML and Javascript either! (all those hooks, commas in JQuery etc. are just too messy, in my opinion...and I hate CSS too).
The way I use PHP now, is that I have written a quite advanced framework, that processes clean xml-templates into HTML/Javascript. This way I can make my own custom HTML-tags, that do all the work of CSS, extra HTML and it creates all Javascript for me automatically...

It's a bit how Delphi for PHP and Prado work. Once the (visual!) PHP-components are done, I can use them over and over again... and only have to think about HTML, CSS and Javascript once, while building the component...

Okay, now my question: since I can't use PHP on the client with PhoneGap, but DO need the HTML,  would it be a crazy idea to let my web-server create the HTML for me the first time the app runs, then store the HTML locally using PhoneGap, and then the next time the app is loaded, reuse the locally stored HTML ?

So my question is :  can I create HTML on a webserver, and then store that HTML locally so my PhoneGap-app can use that?  Or is the HTML in a PhoneGap app somehow 'compiled' and cannot be changed afterwards ?

Or is this a really stupid idea and should I abandon my nice PHP-components framework? What are your thoughts?

Comment: You're going to have to learn or use one of the technologies no matter what, unless you hire a front end developer to do that work for you.

Comment: I do know how to use all the technologies, I just don't like them very much, so I came up with a solution in PHP that does all the dirty work for me.

Comment: It takes care of styling views?

Comment: It's not a real MVC framework, I think. I use XML-files as some kind of turbo-HTML. A (standard) PHP-page proccesses that XML into a complete HTML page. For all operations (database, pdf-creation, graphical stuff, etc.) php-objects are automatically created that do all the hard work... and return the data to the webpage as html, json, pdf, or whatever I want... I think it's quite unique, but very powerful... that's why I wouldn't want to abandon it for my future PhoneGap apps...

Comment: Actually my framework is a bit like ASP.NET, but with PHP :)

Comment: Wow, you like web apps, but you don't like JavaScript, HTML, CSS, Java or C++? You do realize you can't write a full web app with just PHP right?

Comment: Actually, I can, using just xml templates with my own defined tags, which are automatically converted using PHP into HTML, CSS and Javascript for me. I realize this is exotic, but it works beautifully for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give a meaningful answer to a question like this without some context. The big question that you've left unanswered is: What are you really trying to *do*? What will the apps that you create do, and what will make yours different and better than apps that are already out there? Do you want to sell these apps in the app store? Are you trying to collect and/or disseminate mission-specific information for your company?

On the face of it, writing a bunch of HTML and PHP that'll execute on your server just to generate a bunch of HTML and JavaScript that'll execute in a PhoneGap application seems like a lot of trouble. OTOH, if that's what you're most comfortable with, and if you can get it to do what you want, go for it.

If you give your framework a catchy name and make some bold assertions about how it's the newest, fastest best way to develop mobile applications, you can probably turn it into a book deal. ;-) Until that happens though, you'll have a hard time finding answers to questions about writing iPhone apps using PHP.